# FFMpeg giving invalid argument error with python subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a file or microphone stream to 22050 sample rate and change tempo to double. I can do it using terminal with below code;

```
#ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -af asetrate=44100*0.5,aresample=44100,atempo=2 output.mp3
```

But i can not run this terminal code with python subprocess. I try many things but every time fail. Generaly i am taking *Requested output format 'asetrate' or 'aresample' or 'atempo' is not suitable output format* errors. Invalid argument. How can i run it and take a stream with pipe?

```
song = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg.exe", "-i", sys.argv[1], "-f", "asetrate", "22050", "wav", "pipe:1"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two commands are different. Try:

```
song = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", sys.argv[1], "-af", "asetrate=22050,aresample=44100,atempo=2", "-f", "wav", "pipe:1"],
```

- `-af` is for audio filter.
- `-f` is to manually set muxer/output format

Comment: Ok it is working. Thanks a lot.. May i ask you a new question? How can i give a live stream microphone input these code? Accualy i want to change sys.argv[1] parameter with pyaudio callback sound data. Can you give an example or tip about this ? @llogan

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` interprets whatever supplied by `-af` as a single argument that it would then parse internally into separate ones, so splitting them out before passing it via `Popen` would not achieve the same thing.

The initial example using the terminal should be created using `Popen` as

```
subprocess.Popen([
    'ffmpeg', '-i', 'test.mp3', '-af', 'asetrate=44100*0.5,aresample=44100,atempo=2',
    'output.mp3',
])
```

So for your actual example with pipe, try instead the following:

```
song = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg.exe", "-i", sys.argv[1], "-f", "asetrate=22050,wav", "pipe:1"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

You will then need to call [`song.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to get the output produced by `ffmpeg.exe`.

Comment: Ok it is working. Thanks a lot.. May i ask you a new question? How can i give a live stream microphone input these code? Accualy i want to change sys.argv[1] parameter with pyaudio callback sound data. Can you give an example or tip about this ?

Comment: Probably check to see if pyaudio can output to stdout and then pipe it into ffmpeg.